# laravel chunkById stuck in the middle, did I missing something?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, chunks

I want to move my audits table records which got million of rows to another table by using console/command and chunkbyid but it stop in the middle. For example I want to move the audit date of MONTH(created_at) = 02 and YEAR(created_at) = 2021, it does not run through all the records following that condition. As i checked in mysql it suppose to have like 5mils of records but only run up to hundreds thousand only. My codes as below in console

```
        Audit::query()
            ->whereRaw("MONTH(created_at) = '$month'")
            ->whereRaw("YEAR(created_at) = '$year'")
            ->chunkById(1, function ($audits) use ($table_name) {
                foreach($audits as $audit){
                    dump($audit->id);
                    $newRecord = $audit->replicate()->fill([
                        'audit_id' => $audit->id,
                        'created_at' => $audit->created_at,
                        'updated_at' => $audit->updated_at,
                    ]);
                    $newRecord->setTable($table_name);
                    $newRecord->save();

                    if(str_contains($audit->auditable_type, 'User') || str_contains($audit->auditable_type, 'Trans') || str_contains($audit->auditable_type, 'Step')|| str_contains($audit->auditable_type, 'Team')){
                            $audit->delete();
                    }
                }
            }, $column = 'id');
```

[image: in my console]

I already followed many solutions i found in many sites but still not working. Is there anything i missed?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel documentaion (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)
there is a block of note say `When updating or deleting records inside the chunk callback, any changes to the primary key or foreign keys could affect the chunk query. This could potentially result in records not being included in the chunked results.`
and in your code you deleting audit in some cases.

Comment: but i tried to commend all the codes inside the foreach except dump, it still stuck there

Comment: try to retrieve data without **chunkById** function using **get()** and dd data to see exactly which data return.